# Google Kickstart Round D : Record Breaker Problem. Please hep me to debug my program

Tags: python-3.x

```
  Problem
    Isyana is given the number of visitors at her local theme park on N consecutive days. The number of visitors on the i-th day is Vi. A day is record breaking if it satisfies both of the following conditions:
    The number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the number of visitors on each of the previous days.
    Either it is the last day, or the number of visitors on the day is strictly larger than the number of visitors on the following day.
    Note that the very first day could be a record breaking day!
    
    Please help Isyana find out the number of record breaking days.
    
    Input
    The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integer N. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Vi.
    
    Output
    For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of record breaking days.
    
    Limits
    Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
    Memory limit: 1GB.
    1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
    0 ≤ Vi ≤ 2 × 105.
    
    Test set 1
    1 ≤ N ≤ 1000.
    
    Test set 2
    1 ≤ N ≤ 2 × 105 for at most 10 test cases.
    For the remaining cases, 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000.
    
    Sample
    
    Input
        
    Output
     
    4
    8
    1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0
    6
    4 8 15 16 23 42
    9
    3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5
    6
    9 9 9 9 9 9
    
      
    Case #1: 2
    Case #2: 1
    Case #3: 3
    Case #4: 0
    
      
    In Sample Case #1, the bold and underlined numbers in the following represent the record breaking days: 1 2 0 7 2 0 2 0.
    
    In Sample Case #2, only the last day is a record breaking day.
    
    In Sample Case #3, the first, the third, and the sixth days are record breaking days.
    
    In Sample Case #4, there is no record breaking day.
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This python code which i submitted in 'Kickstart Round D problem 1: Record Broker'. I executed this code on my local machine and there wasn't any run time error on top of that I couldn't brute force any test case that could break the code or give wrong answer. But while doing submission in kickstart it gives me runtime error. What could be the issue for getting run time error on kickstart? Please help!

```
cases = int(input().strip())
for q in range(1, cases + 1):
    l = int(input().strip())
    ls = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
    l = len(ls)
    local_max = 0
    count = 0
    for i in range(l):
        if i == 0:
            if ls[1] < ls[0]:
                local_max = ls[0]
                count += 1
            continue
        if i == l - 1:
            if ls[i] > ls[i - 1] and ls[i] > local_max:
                count += 1
            break
        if ls[i] > ls[i - 1] and ls[i] > ls[i + 1] and ls[i] > local_max:
            count += 1
            local_max = ls[i]
            continue
    
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(q, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
if ls[1] < ls[0]:
```

What if ls only has 1 element?

After fixing that your code still returns the wrong answer if there's only 1 element.

Also, consider this test case:

```
"65 87 87 34 64 59 93 20 95 85 24 99 62 100 60 19 100"
```

64 is not valid, but you count it.